# Https on a Amazon Web Service (AWS) EC2 windows without loadbalancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https, certificate

It is possible to get a https on a windows instance without loadbalancer.
Ec2 only.

AWS told me : you won't be able to run the SSL certificate without ELB or Cloudfront.

But not sure about the response.

Comment: Yes, you just have to get the certificate by some other means and install it on your server. Certificates provided by Amazon only work with ELB and Cloudfront.

Answer (score 2):

If you have your own certificate, you can set it up easily, and adjust the security groups to allow HTTPS traffic to your instance. If you don't have any certificate, you can use [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) to generate one to yourself (you have to renew it in every 90 days) this is free.

If you want to use AWS Certificates, you have to use Cloudfront or an ELB.

Comment: I need to log into IIS or some cli exists for that?

Comment: You can achieve that in both ways. You can configure it from the [MMC](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-microsoft-iis-7.htm) or you can do it from [command line](http://www.awesomeideas.net/post/How-to-configure-SSL-on-IIS7-under-Windows-2008-Server-Core.aspx) also